# Troubleshooting user sessions in Rails Blog App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making a blog page just for fun and I am having some trouble with user sessions.

So here is whats going, I create a new user(User1) and everything works fine. BUT when I create an additional user(User2), every time I create an article, or click on another users show page, it redirects everything to the first user(User1). Now let's say I log out of User2 session, then I log back in as User2, it also redirects to User1 profile instead of User2. What is going on? Not sure what I missed.

Here is the link to the github repo github.com/tonymoreno86/alpha-blog.git

Still a sort of a newb with Rails so feel free to let me know what files I need to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you assigning each new article that gets created to the first user and then saving it?  `@article.user = User.first` <-- referring to this line of code in your articles controller create action.

```
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.user = User.first  

    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "Article was successfully created"
      redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: @kparek01 this was to temporarily hardcode a user to articles cause user sign up had not been created yet. Is this whats causing that to happen?

Comment: So that is one of your issues.  The other issue stems from your users controller and how you are trying to find the user ```@user = User.find_by(params[:id])```.  When you run this code in your rails console and provide find_by a number you should receive an error ```ArgumentError (Unsupported argument type: 1 (Integer))```.  So change all your find_by to find and see if you make some progress.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to fix everything.

Comment: Glad you were able to make progress @Tony, keep plugging away.